# Android Studio CRC update error (1.1.0->1.2.2)

Tags: android-studio

While update Android Studio I have faced with the following error:

```
Temp. directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\

java.io.IOException: Data error (CRC)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at com.intellij.updater.Digester.doDigestStream(Digester.java:76)
    at com.intellij.updater.Digester.digestStream(Digester.java:69)
    at com.intellij.updater.Digester.digestRegularFile(Digester.java:21)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.digestFile(Patch.java:371)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.isModified(PatchAction.java:180)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.doValidateNotChanged(PatchAction.java:145)
    at com.intellij.updater.BaseUpdateAction.validate(BaseUpdateAction.java:60)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch$1.forEach(Patch.java:271)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:360)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.validate(Patch.java:267)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.prepareAndValidate(PatchFileCreator.java:68)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.doInstall(Runner.java:293)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.access$000(Runner.java:18)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner$2.execute(Runner.java:261)
    at com.intellij.updater.SwingUpdaterUI$5.run(SwingUpdaterUI.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can't understand what is wrong. But, as the result, because of update is stopped, the first what I observed was nothing to update and the second was the new Android SDK (API 22 MNC preview) can not be properly synchronized with an old Android Studio. So that in Desing Mode we have "Rendering Problem":

```
org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android Studio
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:159)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.create(RenderService.java:197)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:475)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have:

```
Current version: 1.1.0 (build 135.1740770)
Update version:  1.2.2 (build 141.1980579)
```

Did anyone faced with this error? 
What it should be done to fix this issue without reinstall whole IDE?